# Manually associate session with current request asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC 5 asp.net website where I need to expose a number of REST APIs to a stand-alone mobile client.  The rest of the site is using Forms based security where it sets the ASP.NET_SessionId as a cookie, and that is used to authenticate the user with the request after they log in.  With my mobile application, I am not able to use the cookie method because of the cross-doman issue.  What I would like to do is add a header "X-SessionId" with the value of the ASP.NET_SessionId, then on the server side, have a filter that looks for that field, and if it is present, associates the request with the given session.   (Client will log in with an AJAX POST call which will return the ASP.NET_SessionId upon successful login).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
public sealed class CustomSecurityAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{ 

public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-SessionId"]) &&      IsAuthenticated(ilterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-SessionId"]))
        filterContext.Result = new HttpNotFoundResult();
}

private bool IsAuthenticated(string sessionId)
{
    // get your user details from your database (or whatever)
    var user = new UserRepository().Get(sessionId);

    if (user == null)
        return false;

   // build up an identity, use your own or out of the box.
    FormsIdentity itentity = new MyIdentity(user);

   // Set the user
   filterContext.HttpContext.Current.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(itentity , user.Roles);

    return true;
}

}
```

You are going to have to store current sessions in your database, so for example when a user logs in grab the sessionid and stick it in the db, so you know they have 1..n current sessions.

Then you can look it up as part of your authentication.

**Edit:**

Let's take a step back, never mind cookies and sessions for the moment.

You have a website and a restful api, they both servce different purposes and clients and have different security requirements.

So what are the most common options for securing your Api?

- Basic authentication.

  Most restful APIs require a username/password to be sent through with each request, as part of the headers or in the request itself.
- An authentication token

  You can provide a token associated with a user account (a guid could suffice) when requests are made you check for the token.
- Using an existing protocal like [OAuth](http://oauth.net/)

I would recommend using these common scenarios to be sure you don't miss something and open your self up to security vulnerabilities.

Is there a reason you can't use any of these?

Comment: That's a fine start for the filter, however how do I tell asp.net to use the X-SessionId to lookup the (existing) Session and associate the HttpContext.Current.User and all the other variables?

Comment: i've updated my answer for a potential solution, to be honest you are kinda heading off into the wild, there could be better way something like a single sign on solution might be betteR?

Comment: That gets around the security issue (storing the sessions in the db).  I thought ASP.NET has all the sessions stored in an internal datastore (maybe just a map).   Is it possible to reference that so I can put other things into the Session like I can with regular clients?

Comment: Session would work as per normal, also see update above.